# Deserialize from Number value to int (error - no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value) while posting data

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I asked previously basically the same question and solved it somehow, but here is a problem again:

I am sending post data from my Angular 12 app

```
{
  "qty": 2,
  "paid": 200,
  "ticketid": 2
}
```

This is for userticket model which looks like this in java:

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tickettouser")

public class TicketUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
     @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Users userid;

     @Column(name = "qty")
     private int qty;

     @Column(name = "paid")
     private float paid;

     @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler","ignoreUnknown = true"})
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
            @JoinColumn(name = "ticketid", nullable = false)
            @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
            private Tickets ticketid;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Users getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Users userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public float getPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(float paid) {
        this.paid = paid;
    }

    public Tickets getTicketid() {
        return ticketid;
    }

    public void setTicketid(Tickets ticketid) {
        this.ticketid = ticketid;
    }

     
}
```

The full error:

```
2021-11-08 14:07:46.938  WARN 8180 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.model.Tickets` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.model.Tickets` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.example.model.TicketUser["ticketid"])]
```

And my ticket model

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")

public class Tickets {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    
     
     @Column(name = "price")
     private Float price;
    
     @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
            @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
            @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
            private Events eventid;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Events getEventid() {
        return eventid;
    }

    public void setEventid(Events eventid) {
        this.eventid = eventid;
    }

}
```

And finally my ticketuser controller

```
package com.example.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.model.TicketUser;
import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsImp;
import com.example.model.Cities;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;
import com.example.service.UsersticketService;
import com.example.service.EventsService;
import com.example.service.HallsService;
import com.example.service.UsersService;
import com.example.model.Users;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/userticket")
@SpringBootApplication
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8889")

public class UsersTicketController {
    @Autowired
    UsersticketService usersticketService;
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersservice;
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity list()
     {
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
         String usr= auth.getName();
        
         Users user=usersservice.getUserByLogin(usr);
        int id=user.getId();
        List<TicketUser> ticketList=usersticketService.getTicketByUser(id);
        // user.getId();
         //System.out.println(user);
         
         return new ResponseEntity<>(ticketList, HttpStatus.OK);
       
     }
    
     @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody TicketUser ticket)
        {
        
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
         String usr= auth.getName();
        
         Users user=usersservice.getUserByLogin(usr);
        Users userid=new Users();
        userid.setId(user.getId());
         ticket.setUserid(userid);
         
         usersticketService.addTicket(ticket);
          return new ResponseEntity<>(ticket, HttpStatus.CREATED);

        }
     @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
     usersticketService.deleteTicket(id);

return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

    }
}
```

As you can see I don't use any custom deserialize methods or somethin like that. How this problem can be solved?
I see this error if I try to use add method in my controller

Will add TicketuserRepository:

```
package com.example.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.model.TicketUser;
import com.example.model.Users;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;

@Repository

public interface TicketsUserRepository extends CrudRepository<TicketUser, Integer> {
    Page<Events> findByuserid(Integer userid, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Events> findByuseridAndId(Integer userid, Integer id);


    Page<Events> findByticketid(Integer ticketid, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Events> findByticketidAndId(Integer ticketid, Integer id);

    List<TicketUser> findByUserid(int id);

}
```

and the service

```
package com.example.service;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.model.TicketUser;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.example.repository.TicketsUserRepository;
import com.example.repository.EventsRepository;
import com.example.repository.HallsRepository;
@Service
@Transactional

public class UsersticketServiceImplementation implements UsersticketService {

    @Autowired
    TicketsUserRepository ticketsuserRepository;
    
    @Override
    public List<TicketUser> getAllTickets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<TicketUser>) ticketsuserRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public TicketUser getTicketById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ticketsuserRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTicket(TicketUser ticketuser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ticketsuserRepository.save(ticketuser);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTicket(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ticketsuserRepository.deleteById(id);
        
    }

    @Override
    public List<TicketUser> getTicketByUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<TicketUser>) ticketsuserRepository.findByUserid(id);
    }
    

}
```

This is my model userticket in angular:

```
import {Ticket} from "./ticket.model";

export class Userticket {
  id?:any;
  qty?:number;
  paid?:number;

  ticketid?:Ticket;

}
```

Will add my ticketuser comonent from angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from 'src/app/services/event.service';
import { Event } from 'src/app/models/event.model';
import {TicketService} from 'src/app/services/ticket.service';
import {Ticket} from "../../models/ticket.model";
import {Userticket} from "../../models/userticket.model";
import {UserticketService} from "../../services/userticket.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userticket-buy',
  templateUrl: './userticket-buy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userticket-buy.component.css']
})
export class UserticketBuyComponent implements OnInit {
  currentTicket: Ticket = {
    price: 0,
    eventid:this.retrieveEvents()



  };
  eventid = this.currentTicket.eventid;

  events?: Event[];
  submitted = false;

  currentUserTicket: Userticket = {
    qty: 1,
    paid:0,



  };
  //final current

  //end
  message = ''

  constructor(
    private eventService: EventService,
    private ticketService:TicketService,
    private userticketService:UserticketService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.message = '';
    this.getTicket(this.route.snapshot.params.id);

  }
  getTicket(id: string): void {
    this.ticketService.get(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.currentTicket = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
  //save order
  saveOrder(): void {
    const data = {
      qty: this.currentUserTicket.qty,
      paid: this.currentUserTicket.paid,

      ticketid: this.currentTicket.id

    };
    //console.log(data.eventid);
    this.userticketService.create(data)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("city")
          console.log(response);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
  //end

  retrieveEvents(): any {
    this.eventService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.events = data;
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          return error;
        });

  }
  calculatePrice($event:any){
  let n1:number|undefined;
  n1=this.currentTicket.price;
    let n2:number|undefined;
    n2=this.currentUserTicket.qty  || 1;
    let res:number|undefined;
   res=n1  || 1 * n2  || 1;
  console.log(this.currentUserTicket.qty);
    // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
    this.currentUserTicket.paid= this.currentUserTicket.qty*this.currentTicket.price

  }
}
```

And the template:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="currentTicket.id" class="edit-form">
    <h4>Билет</h4>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Количество</label>
        <input type="number"
               class="form-control"
               id="title"
               [(ngModel)]="currentUserTicket.qty"
               name="qty"
               (keyup)="calculatePrice($event)"
        />


        <input
          type="hidden"
          class="form-control"
          id="id"
          [(ngModel)]="currentTicket"
          name="ticketid"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Итого</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          id="paid"
          [(ngModel)]="currentUserTicket.paid"
          name="paid"
        />


      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

        <p>Событие: {{currentTicket.eventid?.name}}</p>
        <p>Зал: {{currentTicket.eventid?.hallid?.name}}</p>
        <p>Город: {{currentTicket.eventid?.cityid?.name}}</p>





      </div>

    </form>



    <button
      type="submit"
      class="badge badge-success mb-2"
      (click)="saveOrder()"
    >
      Подтвердить
    </button>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="!currentTicket.id">
    <br />
    <p>Нет доступа...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Will add my working example from ticket model:
tickets.java

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")

public class Tickets {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    
     
     @Column(name = "price")
     private Float price;
    
     @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
            @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
            @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
            private Events eventid;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Events getEventid() {
        return eventid;
    }

    public void setEventid(Events eventid) {
        this.eventid = eventid;
    }

}
```

TicketsRepository:

```
package com.example.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.model.Tickets;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;

@Repository

public interface TicketsRepository  extends CrudRepository<Tickets, Integer>{
    
    
    Page<Events> findByeventid(Integer eventid, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Events> findByeventidAndId(Integer eventid, Integer id);

}
```

TicketService:

```
package com.example.service;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.model.Tickets;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.example.repository.EventsRepository;
import com.example.repository.HallsRepository;
import com.example.repository.TicketsRepository;
@Service
@Transactional

public class TicketsServiceImplementation implements TicketsService {

    @Autowired
    TicketsRepository ticketsRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Tickets> getAllTickets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<Tickets>) ticketsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Tickets getTicketById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ticketsRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTicket(Tickets ticket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ticketsRepository.save(ticket);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTicket(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ticketsRepository.deleteById(id);
        
    }

}
```

And the controller:

```
package com.example.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.model.Tickets;
import com.example.model.Events;
import com.example.model.Halls;
import com.example.service.TicketsService;
import com.example.service.EventsService;
import com.example.service.HallsService;

@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8889")

@RequestMapping(value="/ticket")
@SpringBootApplication

public class TicketsController {
    @Autowired
    TicketsService ticketsService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity list()
     {
         List<Tickets> ticketList=ticketsService.getAllTickets();
         
         return new ResponseEntity<>(ticketList, HttpStatus.OK);
       
     }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody Tickets ticket)
    {
     ticketsService.addTicket(ticket);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(ticket, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
     ticketsService.deleteTicket(id);

return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/getone/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity getOne(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
    Tickets ticket= ticketsService.getTicketById(id);

     return new ResponseEntity<>(ticket, HttpStatus.OK);
       
    }
}
```

Basically this is the ticket table controller. It was basically made a same way as UserTicket. Why then I am getting this problem?

Comment: Pls add more details of the service class how are you saving ticketUser entity

Comment: Got it. Added service and repository in case if it would help.

Comment: There's way too much code here. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For now no errors there.

Comment: @MCVE I would be glad to make a small example but have no idea wich method produces this error.

Comment: Anythin else I should add to help solve a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that in the model you are using a full object of ticket and that is also marked as `nullable = false` so while saving the model in database you need to create an object of ticket using the`ticketId` attribute in the request json or change the model’s attribute from type `Tickets` to `int`
You are already doing the same thing for user by setting user object.

Comment: Is there any example on how to create that request Json?

Comment: Or yet how can I save a relationsheep beetween tickets table and ticketUser table if I will change it to int?

Comment: Your ticket model have further relation to events,that will also need to be populated whole saving the relationship. Also it depends on use case how you want to save you may save ticket separately and then associate it with the user. In the request you are sending requestId that means this ticket is an existing ticket in the database? If so tou can read it from database first and them associate it with TicketUser model before saving

Comment: Greate. That is exectly what I am doing. I can provide my angular 12 component as an example. I mean getting it from db and then saving. Plus it works normaly on other models like events, cities, etc.

Comment: I have added a Ticket table entity that works basicly a same way.